# Is speech final in Poker?

Tags: texas-hold-em, rules, all-in

We were playing poker with a few friends.

Once we were heads up, I went all-in. The other player said he's all-in. But didn't move any chips forward.

Right after that, he said: "Nevermind. I fold."

Is this allowed? I told him he might've gotten a reaction from me to make him fold.

But he argued that he didn't put in any chips, and that putting in chips is final. So I told him it's okay, as I don't know the rule. Based on his cards I would double up. In the end I still won though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> In poker, a "verbal declaration" is when you verbally declare what
>   your move is going to be. Verbal declarations are binding.

He's all in and you should proceed. He was doing it to get a reaction or just messing about, either way its binding.